# FD_ISSET returns 0 after FD_SET

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, set, file-descriptor

I have the following code:

```
FD_SET(mc_sock, &readfds);

foo = FD_ISSET(mc_sock, &readfds); // returns 1

// Wait until some socket on the set is ready to be read 
while(select (FD_SETSIZE,&readfds,NULL,NULL,ptv))  { 

foo = FD_ISSET(mc_sock, &readfds); // returns 0
```

I add mc_sock to *readfds* and FD_ISSET returns 1 as expected. However later when inside while loop FD_ISSET returns 0 without calling FD_CLR. 
The code jumps into the while when I run a MobileC server but there isn't any FD_CLR in the code runned. 
I'm quite a newbie in sets and file descriptors and I haven't found out what's happening. Do you have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `ptv`? How do you initialize it?

Comment: Furthermore, `select` can return negative values and you **must** check for them and examine `errno`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second, third, and forth arguments of [`select(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) are **in-out** parameters, meaning the call modifies them to let you know about what events had happened upon return. This is why you need to re-arm the file descriptor sets before every call to `select(2)`.

Also look into other de-multiplexing facilities like [`poll(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and [`epoll(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html).